# Generating a Word Document with C# using publipostage library dll

Tags: c#, dll, ms-word

I'm doing my end-of-study internship in a development company, and my mission is to upgrade a maintenance management platform. One of the functionalities i need to add is generating invoices as word format using c# and publipostage library .dll, but when i try to run my code i get an error: PublipostageException

[PublipostageException Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyiw4.png)

**Code**

```
public void GenererEtatFacture() {
        int IdFacture = int.Parse(Request["IdFacture"]);
        PublipostageLibrary.BLMoulinette publi = new PublipostageLibrary.BLMoulinette();
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCR"].ConnectionString;
        publi.Cnxstrg = conString;

        //try { 
              publi.OpenPubipostage(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("/","bin/Structure.xml")));

       // }catch(Exception e){
          //Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
      //  }

        publi.SetReportParams("IdFacture", "" + IdFacture);
        var x = publi.LireModele(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("/","Doc/facture.htm"))); 

        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=facture.doc");
        HttpContext.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
        HttpContext.Response.Write(publi.StrutureExplore().ToString());
        HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Response.End(); 

    }
}
```

**structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<Publipostage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Publipostage.xsd">
<NomModele>test Modele</NomModele>
<Separateur>
<![CDATA[<br clear="all" style='page-break-before:always'>]]>
</Separateur>
<Sections>
    <Section>
        <SectionName>Corps</SectionName>
        <SectionPrincipale>true</SectionPrincipale>
        <Datasource>select * from etatFacture</Datasource>
        <RelationField></RelationField>
        <SectionType>Texte</SectionType>
        <Body></Body>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VRefFacture</Variable>
                <FieldSource>RefFacture</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>



        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VNumBC</Variable>
                <FieldSource>NumBC</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VNomComplet</Variable>
                <FieldSource>NomComplet</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VAdresse</Variable>
                <FieldSource>Adresse</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VIdFacture</Variable>
                <FieldSource>IdFacture</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>
        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VTVA</Variable>
                <FieldSource>TVA</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VTotalTH</Variable>
                <FieldSource>TotalTH</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VTotalTTC</Variable>
                <FieldSource>TotalTTC</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VMontantLettre</Variable>
                <FieldSource>MontantLettre</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Header></Header>
        <ReportParams>
            <ReportParam>
                <Field>IdFacture</Field>
                <Value></Value>
                <Type>Numerique</Type>
            </ReportParam>
            <ReportParam>
                <Field>DateSystem</Field>
                <Value></Value>
                <Type>Date</Type>
            </ReportParam>
        </ReportParams>
    </Section>


    <Section>
        <SectionName>VDescription</SectionName>
        <SectionType>Tableau</SectionType>
        <Body>
            <![CDATA[ <tr>
              <td>
                <p><span>- VValeurDescription</span></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p><span>- VQuantite</span></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p><span>- VPrixUnitaire</span></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p><span>- VPrixTotal</span></p>
              </td>
             </tr>
            ]]>
        </Body>
        <SectionPrincipale>false</SectionPrincipale>
        <Datasource>Select * from DescriptionFacture</Datasource>
        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VValeurDescription</Variable>
                <FieldSource>ValeurDescription</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>

        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VQuantite</Variable>
                <FieldSource>Quantite</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>
        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VPrixUnitaire</Variable>
                <FieldSource>PrixUnitaire</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>
        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VPrixTotal</Variable>
                <FieldSource>PrixTotal</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>
        <Variables>
            <Mappings>
                <Variable>VIdFacture</Variable>
                <FieldSource>IdFacture</FieldSource>
            </Mappings>
        </Variables>
        <RelationField>
            <SlaveField>IdFacture</SlaveField>
            <SectionName>VDescription</SectionName>
            <MasterInfo>
                <MasterField>IdFacture</MasterField>
                <SectionName>Corps</SectionName>
            </MasterInfo>
        </RelationField>
        <Footer><![CDATA[</TABLE>]]></Footer>
        <Header>
            <![CDATA[<TABLE border=1>
            <TR>
                <TD>Désignation</TD>
                <TD>QTE</TD>
                <TD>PU / HT</TD
                <TD>PT / HT</TD>

            </TR>]]>
        </Header>
</Section>
```

I searched for this error but have found nothing.

Comment: The displayed error message is "`PublipostageException was unhandled by user code`". So you need to handle it.

Comment: yeah i know but what's the main cause of this error

Comment: like what causes this exception in my code.